# Как в Telethon отправить сообщению в тему группы?

Tags: python, telethon

Проблема в том, что сам чат имеет общий id для всех тем и если ты отправляешь сообщение по этому id он отправляет её в тему general, при этом ответить на сообщение в Теме возможно. Подскажите как отправлять сообщение в нужную тему группы через telethon

Answer (score 0):

В общем сам спросил - сам отвечаю:
не знаю каким образом, но когда телеграмм делит обычный чат на категории, каждой категории присваивается целочисленный идентификатор сообещенния и что бы отправить сообщение в нужную категорию необходимо указать этот параметр в методе

```
send_message('id чата или ссылка', 'Cамо сообщение', reply_to = "идентификатор группы в чате")
```

Мне этот мир теперь абсолютно понятен, всем удачи